# Is it possible to put a mathematical formula (using Latex) next to the Slider widget in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider

My question is in the title, as you can see in the image below my variable is `M2/M1` and I am wondering if it is possible to replace it by `$\dfrac{M_2}{M_1}$`.

I tried:

```
axmass  = plt.axes([0.18, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
smass = Slider(axmass, '$\dfrac{M_2}{M_1}$', 1e-5, 1, 0)
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError:
\dfrac{M_2}{M_1}
^
Unknown symbol: \dfrac (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, this should work, it adds an `r` before the string, it uses \frac instead of \dfrac (display mode is not supported), it uses rc (if not, the result is ugly).

After request I also added a line to vertically center the fraction (if not the fraction line is not aligned with the slider), I am open to suggestion for a better way to position correctly the legend !

Here is a minimal working exemple adapted from [this STACK OVERFLOW question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43995590/change-matplotlib-slider-label-text-size):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.widgets

fig = plt.figure()
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
E0_slider_ax = fig.add_axes([0.6, 0.2, 0.25, 0.03], facecolor="skyblue")
E0_slider =  matplotlib.widgets.Slider(E0_slider_ax, r'$\frac{M_3}{M_1}$', 1,  100, valinit = 50)
E0_slider.label.set_size(40)
E0_slider.label.set_position((-0.1,0)) #Probably not the best solution
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can take a look at matplotlib official documentation on the subject: https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to center it though (the fraction line centered with the slider axis) ? or change its size as well as the size of the number on the right ?

Comment: I've edited my answer to center the fraction line. If you want a proper solution I suggest you open a new question on Stackoverflow. 

For the record I tried `E0_slider.label.set_verticalalignment("bottom")` , but no alignment seems to work.